# How can i parse a PHP array from Android SDK?

Tags: java, php, android, regex, arrays

I dont like others do my duties, but i'm not a RegEx expert and i think you guys would be a great help.

I'm building a newsletter Android app which consumes an array exposed in a http like this:

```
Array
(
    [Last_News] => Array
    (
        [last-news-1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 711
                [Title] => Here goes the title text
                [Bullet] => Here goes the basic description of the news.
            )

)
```

I'm trying with RegEx this:

```
String pattern = ".Ultima_Hora. => Array . .ultima_hora-[0-9]*.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);


    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) { // Find each match in turn; String can't do this.
        //String s = m.group();
    String s = m.toString();
         txt.setText(s);

    }
```

But then, when i run my app, i can see all the text downloaded from my httpclient implementation. 
Someone can give a example of how i can print the arrays inside [last-news-1]?
Thank you very much.

Comment: why not go for JSON?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with asking for help, once you've hit your head against something long enough. and yeah, as pointed out, passing data between application is what JSON is for. both android and php can talk json natively.

Comment: I asked the same for the guys they've exposed the "webservice". If JSOL or XML would be used by them, i could parse with some available libraries quickier than you answered :). The site is [this](http://excelsior.com.mx/iPad)

Comment: @Enrique: Is that Spanish or Portuguese?

Comment: Also, what kind of webservice print_r their output? =S

Comment: @Alix Axel, @Jonah @yoda @Oren Mazor: They told me that "this" was their webservice, because, as you can see, they use it to consume the iPad app they built also. Do you recommend talk with them and ask for change to JSON?

Comment: @Enrique: Abso-****-lutley, if you can, of course. Also, are you sure their iPad app uses this exact output?

Comment: Well, they said that to me, but i'm going to ask how they did it to feed their app. I got worried also because it's very useless do this way, especially when the standards are JSON and XML. Thank you anyway Alix Axel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of flavor Java uses but in PHP I would use the following regexes:

```
\[ID\] => (.*)
\[Title\] => (.*)
\[Bullet\] => (.*)
```

Now the problem is if each key is allowed to have newlines in it, in that case I would do:

```
\[ID\] => ([^\[]*)
\[Title\] => ([^\[]*)
\[Bullet\] => ([^\[]*)
```

But then it won't match the whole string if it contains a `[` but I guess that's the price you have to pay.

Comment: Ok, when i try \[ID\] => (.*) the SDK doesnt make any noise and runs well, but when my app is deployed in my device, show all the plain text again. When i try as matcher \\[ID\\] => ([^[]*) says an error in runtime saying that need the [.

Comment: @Enrique: The (.*) is a group capture, I don't know how you access a group capture with Java but I guess it has something to do with that commented `m.group()` line? Also, try dropping the `m.toString()` and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, you can use the method m.group to print the match m. However, i will need to do a simple example in Java of how to use RegEx. Thanks a lot :)